# Error on Eclipse ADT while creating an Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-resources

I've already tried everything I saw in the forum but it seems that doesn't work for me. I really need to finish this project until Nov. 25th but I'm stuck at the creation of the project.

Eclipse is full of errors, like this:

> [2014-11-05 20:59:48 - TEXApp]
>   D:\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190:
>  error:
>   Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimary'.
>
> [2014-11-05 20:59:48 - TEXApp]
>  
>   D:\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: 
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.

There's a lot of them, I don't know what's wrong since I installed all the libraries.

Here's how I set up the project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zBZn.png

And this is what I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcNAV.png

Some times I delete the components which have errors, but I still get the themes_base.xml errors and my R.java is not generated.

Sorry for the long text but, I don't know what to do, hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your application has the reference of the library `appcompat_v7`, Delete the `android-support-v4.jar`library of your project under `/libs` folder, that is already defined into the `appcompat_v7` library.

Having two `android-support-v4.jar` libraries defined into the same project are causing that problem.

**Install the last version of the SDK, the problem was solved.**

Comment: Still doesn't work, I can't see what's wrong. The styles_base.xml has an error in this line:

    <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView"
               parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView">
    </style>

I don't know, but I think the appcompat library is broken, I tried downloading it again but it still doesn't work.

Comment: in "problems" delete all the errors and clean  your project.